# How can I unit test a class that interacts with Git?

Tags: c#, git, unit-testing

I'm writing a program that extracts information from Git repositories. I'm working on a class called `GitLog` that extracts the commit logs. Basically, it spins up a process to run a '`git log`' command and captures whatever comes back on stdout into stream reader. The gist of the method is this (we can assume here that `GitWorkingCopyPath` is valid and points to a Git working copy, the rest of this code is completely untested, which is the point of the question really):

```
public StreamReader GetLogStream()
    {
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("git.exe", "log");
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.WorkingDirectory = GitWorkingCopyPath;
    var process = Process.Start(psi);
    return process.StandardOutput;
    }
```

Obviously this is very tied up with having a working copy somewhere on disk. I'm trying to think how I would unit test this method, without having to have a Git repository laying around, or whether that's even possible.

Perhaps I'm obsessing over the details and this isn't unit testable. Moving up one level of abstraction, it's quite easy to see how I can mock out the whole GitLog class and just return some canned results. So am I trying to drill down into too much detail here? How would you approach this?

Comment: You might want to look at libgit2 - http://libgit2.github.com/

Comment: @lee That is a great suggestion(+1), however for the one command I need (git log) I think it is easier just to use git.exe. Perhaps not the cleanest solution but libgit2 introduces some licensing considerations that I don't want to deal with, and looks like it would be more work for just the one command I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by refactoring the method to make it unit-test-friendly:

```
public StreamReader GetLogStream(ProcessStartInfo psi)
{
    ...
```

Then the normal code calls the method via `GetLogStream(new ProcessStartInfo("git.exe", "log")) ...`

and your unit test code passes in a dummy script that mocks git.

Comment: That's not a bad idea... I will give that a go. Thank you.

Comment: I'm accepting this as my answer now that I have it working. Thank you for the idea. It was not a smooth journey though, I had all kinds of problems getting it working including Visual Studio 2012 saving my .vbs file in an encoding that the VBScript compiler couldn't understand! Took me ages to work out why my script wasn't running. I don't *love* the idea of spawning processes in my unit tests, but it does get the job done and I think I am going to stick with it.

Comment: "I don't love the idea of spawning processes in my unit tests, but it does get the job done and I think I am going to stick with it" - That's pretty much my view too. If possible, I avoid it, but sometimes it's the only way to test some code. Glad the idea was of use to you.